# 220 **** smtp banner while telnet mail server on a Windows XP , hmail server linksys WRT120 n router

Tags: smtp, router, email-server, linksys, banner

we have setup server ,mail server using HMail server and oyr RDNS / PTr is also solved  but when do smtp test from mxtoolbox.com we are getting 220 *********  kind of message.

our server configuration :

OS : windows XP
Mail Server : Hmail Server

IP : Staic IP

Router : Cisco LInksys WRT12N

is this some thing related to router or what .. becouse if telnet the smtp in the same PC where hmailerver installed we are getting 220 domain.com as message . which is fine for us  but when test fromoutside the rotuer we are getting 220 *******

how to fix this

Answer (score 2):

I am no "Hmail Server" expert, but according to its documentation, you just need to change the SMTP banner:

- In the "Hmail server" settings:

  Configuration | SMTP settings | Welcome message

Comment: ,hmailserver settings is fine. but outside the router from external pcs i am getting this kind of error .. is this router error

Comment: So you are saying that your mail server do not display its banner on local but only from outside ? What about other PCs on your side of the router ?

Comment: its showing the desired  as 220 mydomain.com    when telnet PC with in the router .

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before and it's related to the Cisco router. It's performing traffic inspection on the SMTP/ESMTP protocol and blocking anything that doesn't look right.

The 'solution' is to disable ESMTP inspection on the router. The instructions for this are different for each device and I can't find specific instruction for your router. I've included a link that should help, otherwise read the manual: http://www.binarywar.com/2009/11/cisco-pixasa-causes-smtp-banner-corruption/

Comment: It is considered good practice to include the relevant information of the link. As some day the link might become unavailable and then your answer will become useless.

Comment: updated my answer with more info, but I'm not providing instructions as I'm not familiar with that particular device.